# Module is Direct Sum of Cyclic Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is every $R$-module the direct sum of cyclic submodules? It seems to me that the answer is yes, as for any $R$-module $M$ we have that 
$$
\bigoplus_{r\in M} Rr = M.
$$

Containment in both directions is (seemingly) obvious. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at $R = \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ and $M = \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, the simplest example (it's even finite!).

Well, $\displaystyle \bigoplus_{r \in M} Rr = (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)0 \oplus (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)1 \oplus (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)2 = 0 \oplus (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z) \oplus (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z) = (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z)^2 = R^2$, but $M = R$!

In fact, $\displaystyle \left| \bigoplus_{r \in M} Rr \right| = 3 \times 3 \ne 3 = |M|$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the answer is NO (see Kenny's answer). However this question is very interesting and there is a class of rings for which the answer is YES (for a certain choice of generators $r$, not **all** $r\in M$ of course).

See
**I. S. Cohen and I. Kaplansky**, *Rings for which every module is a direct sum of cyclic modules*, in Cambridge, Mass. and Chicago, Ill. Mathematische Zeitschrift, Band 54, Heft 2, S. 97--101 (1951).

Comment: For a similar flavour, it might be worth mentioning that all semisimple modules are also direct sums of cyclic modules.

Comment: @QiZhu You're right ! as simple modules are cyclic. I often used the following (maybe folklore ?) characterization of simple modules. Roughly said, they are cyclic "from everywhere". A simple $A$-module is a module $M$ such that $(\forall x\in M\setminus \{0\})(A.x=M)$.